# How to use Power BI REST API to set Databricks access key on a datasource?

Tags: powerbi, databricks, azure-databricks, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to set a Databricks access key credential in a Power BI datasource through REST API calls.

I own the dataset and can set the key through the Power BI service web UI (app.powerbi.com)

But when I try to do this through REST APIs (e.g., with `curl`) I am getting stuck

I found my way to the datasource via the dataset:

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}/datasources
```

Then I got a response back like

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://wabi-us-east2-c-primary-redirect.analysis.windows.net/v1.0/myorg/groups/xxx/$metadata#datasources","value":[
    {
      "datasourceType":"Extension","connectionDetails":{
        "path":"{\"host\":\"adb-xxxx.xx.azuredatabricks.net\",\"httpPath\":\"\\/sql\\/1.0\\/warehouses\\/xxxx\"}","kind":"Databricks"
      },"datasourceId":"xxxxx","gatewayId":"xxxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using this response I tried making a call like this

```
PATCH https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/xxxx/datasources/xxxx
```

with body:

```
{
   "credentialDetails": "{\"credentialData\":[{\"name\":\"key\", \"value\":\"dapiXXXXX-X\"}]}",
   "credentialType": "Key",
   "privacyLevel": "None",
   "encryptionAlgorithm": "None"
}
```

And I get back this error:

```
{"error":{"code":"UnknownError","pbi.error":{"code":"UnknownError","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}%
```

I think I saw something about encrypting the credentials but I am unable to get the Gateway public key through the APIs (/myorg/gateways returned empty list); and anyhow this is a cloud resource, not using an on-prem gateway, and I am able to set credentials through the web UI.

What am I missing, or doing wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to add a databricks datasource to my dataset using the api but so far I haven't had any luck. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be oversight on my part.  I forgot `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` on my `curl` command.

SMH.